# which sourcesafe is integrated with vb.net(vb 2010)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

We used sourcesafe 6.0 in vb.net.But we get hanged project whenever other one checked out the forms in that project firstly and others check out another ones.How do we solve it?Or sourcesafe 6.0 is not integrated with vb.net?

regards,
naychi

Comment: why not use TFS or svn ? Sourcesafe is quite old now.

Comment: SVN is nearly just as old. Instead, I would use git.

Comment: SVN was last updated in June 2013; SourceSafe in 2005; I think you have different meanings for the word "old".

Answer (score 4):

SourceSafe was last updated in 2005, so it's basically dead. You should consider adopting a newer version control system.

Microsoft offer [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ff637362.aspx). There are plenty of excellent, free, alternatives, ranging from [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) (centralised version control), to [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (both distributed version control). All of these offer integration with Visual Studio.

If you want hosted version control, there's Microsoft's [Team Foundation Service](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/), or there's [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/), for example.

Comment: Besides TFS, Git, SVN, you may also check SourceAnywhere. It is designed as VSS replacment and comes with VSS import tool and Visual Studio integration. http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/version-control-source-control-sourceanywhere.aspx  Disclaimer: I work for the company.